# getting can't find active_record error, why, it worked fine yesterday

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Ugh, I'm not sure what happened, but when I tried to run my development environment, I get this:

```
vendor/bundler_gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:271:in `require_frameworks': no such file to load -- active_record (RuntimeError)
```

I'm pretty sure I made pretty much no changes, I did do a rake cron, and that worked fine, but now I don't know how to debug this.

I can't do a restore with a git to the last HEAD because it says not writeable...help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you updated your gems and didn't specify which rails version your application should use... And with the new rails version the old structure doenst run (if you only specified to take the last rails version)..

Try to install the correct rails version again..

Comment: I'mnot sure what I did, but i just did a fresh checkout, removed some old rails gems such as rails 3.0.3 and it appears to be working again...scary....